# Embed doxygen in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, doxygen

I use mediawiki for the majority of my documentation.  However, we recently started using doxygen to document the API on one of our C/C++ heavy projects.  To give our overall documentation a consistent look & feel, I'd like to embed the doxygen stuff into mediawiki.  How should I do that?

I've looked at some of the extensions, but everything I've found so far seems half-baked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only extension I know of is [DoxyWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDoxyWiki#English%3a_DoxyWiki_history_and_rationale). I think that's all that is available right now.

But perhaps that is what you meant by "half-baked"?

(See also: [Wikis and Wikipedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716))

Comment: Right, that is what I meant by half-baked.  The download link is broken on that site and last updated back in 2008.

Comment: @melonakos - I'm afraid that's all there is, at the moment. :(

Comment: If you haven't found a solution and need a place to start, https://github.com/Coburn37/DoxygenMediawikiBot worked pretty well for me. I made this a few months ago and it got the job done when I needed it although some of the corner case doxygen documents are buggy on the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried DoxyWiki.

You could code a wiki Special page like [Special:FileSystem](http://Extension:FileSystem) or set up a namespace whose "subpages" correspond to doxygen HTML files in the file system. The problem is doxygen wants to render its own navigation which is kinda incompatible with a typical MediaWiki skin's sidebar and such.

You could put the doxygen HTML files in another directory on your web server and link to them. To make this cleaner you could define an [interwiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interwiki) prefix for it, like "docs", and then you can link to the doxygen web pages withh regular wiki links `[[docs:php/Action_8php.html|see the Action.php reference docs]]`. You could skin the doxygen output to make it look more like your wiki's skin.  But your wiki's search box won't return doxygen matches.